# Fetch XML files from a web service to iPhone faster?

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, web-services

I am developing a iPhone App coupled with a .Net Web Service as the Backend. Need few clarifications on the same.

The configuration of my project.

SQL SERVER2008 to store the data, .Net Framework 3.5 to provide Web Service interface, Iphone 3.1.

The Project Description: The SQL Server will store my data in the form of XMLs. Each XML will contain a information about a particular entity. These entities will be displayed in the iPhone as topics in chronological order from A-Z. What is the best possible method to fetch those XMLs from SQL SERVER using a Web Service to the iPhone?

I have a solution like I will fetch all the XMLs available in DB and compress it into a ZIP file using GZIP and store the ZIP in a file system. Then on a request from iPhone to the Web Service, the Web Service will embed the file system path as URLs in the response XML. The iPhone will receive the XML with the URL to fetch the ZIP embedded in it. Then iPhone will make a call to the URL and fetch the file and uncompress it into SQLite DB. What are the drawbacks that is found in this solution? What is the best way to transfer my XML files from Web Service backend to my iPhone as there may be more than 1000 files to be transferred and more than 1000 users will be accessing the system parallely?

Comment: Why do you have to send all 1000 at a time?

Comment: Also, how is this any different from your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152685/how-to-connect-a-iphone-to-a-net-web-service-and-get-1000s-xml-files-efficientl

Comment: You are going to fetch all the XMLs in DB and compress? Thousands of times in parallel? Ouch.  You either need to clarify your question or throw out the design and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Only present enough information about an entity for a user to decide whether or not to download the entire entity. Only send entities to the iPhone device that users request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Intel's SOA Expressway? It can pull data from SQL Server, compress it, expose it as a web service and support 1000's of parallel users.

Check out www.intel.com/soae/software

OR

www.dynamicperimeter.com/

Comment: I created a WCF REST Service to accomplish the task. Now its woring fine with desired performance.